# SharePoint 2013 App Backup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have added a SharePoint app from SharePoint store.This app cannot have the setting option. This app can only handle in edit web part mode. Now i want to use this same app into another SharePoint Server. How to move this into another server?

Please suggest an idea, How to move an app into another SharePoint Server.

Answer (score 3):

Once you add an app from store to your site collection,it will be available for that whole web application.You can just access from site contents.

Answer (score 0):

Publish app in app catalog to access from any site collection.

otherwise you have publish individually for every site collection.

find here what is app catalog [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78002/sharepoint-apps-what-is-app-catalog)

Comment: If i need to use the app into another SharePoint server. At the time what i want to do ? please suggest your idea.

Comment: The person already says that he has added app from SharePoint store. He is not developing it through development tool so App catalog is not in picture here..